# Conectar java y javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Pueden informarme sobre cómo pasar valores de variables entre java y javaScript, al igual en cómo puedo llamar a métodos java desde javascript
Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: Primefaces permite hacer eso por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estás empezando, quizá la manera más sencilla y primitiva sea a través de JSP(java server page). Permite enviar directamente datos de java a javaScript. Las páginas jsp se compilan en un html que se envía al cliente.

Aquí un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<%
  String str="Hello world";
%>
<script>
    var jsvar = <%=str%>;
</script>
```

- Documentación JSP: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html
- Librería JSP: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/index.html
- Autor original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473268/connect-java-with-javascript-for-data-visualization-in-browser/14473303#14473303

Una vez conozcas los JSPs, podrías hacer uso de librerías por encima de JSP como JSTL: http://desarrollo-java.readthedocs.io/es/latest/tutorial6.md.html

Por supuesto, tampoco deberías dejar de mirar los Servlets y las llamadas ajax. Aquí te dejo información sobre una implementación sencilla de stackOverflow con diferentes librerías de javaScript contra Serlvets de Java: http://desarrollo-java.readthedocs.io/es/latest/tutorial6.md.html

Comment: Creo que te olvidaste de traducir algunas partes que quedaron en inglés cuando lo copiaste de https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473303/5290909. **Deberías atribuir al autor original**, no sólo por cortesía, sino también por derechos de copyright.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón del mundo, se me fue.

Comment: Gracias.
Lo probaré a ver si consigo hacer algo interesante

Comment: No sería posible crear un .jar estreno al código JavaScript y llamar a sus funciones desde JavaScript ?

Comment: Supongo que hablas de los applets. Es un sistema que está en desuso. Por seguridad los applets están siendo desactivados en la mayoría de navegadores

Comment: Los applets si los he usado pero como dices vienes desactivados

Comment: Me refiero a algo estilo demonio de Linux pero poderte comunicar con él desde una web

Comment: Porque que se ejecute en el cliente solo sería posible con los applets verdad. Mi idea sería hacer aplicaciones de escritorio con la parte lógica en java y la interfaz gráfica en html ccs y JavaScript